# Why can't I substitute a generic with types specified for a generic without in a method call?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I have a class `Constraint`

`public class Constraint <V: Hashable, D>`

I have a struct `CSP`

`public struct CSP <V: Hashable, D>`

It has a collection of constraints

`var constraints = Dictionary<V, [Constraint<V, D>]>()`

with method addConstraint

`public mutating func addConstraint(constraint: Constraint<V, D>)`

I have a CSP of String and Int.  I want to add a constraint of type String and Int.  It is a subtype of Constraint (well a subtype of a subtype):

`class SendMoreMoneyConstraint<V, D>: ListConstraint <String, Int>`

This doesn't work.

```
csp = CSP<String, Int>(variables: variables, domains: domains)
let smmc = SendMoreMoneyConstraint<String, Int>(variables: variables)
csp.addConstraint(smmc)
```

The last line causes an error of type `Cannot invoke 'addConstraint' with an argument list of type '(SendMoreMoneyConstraint<String, Int>)'`

Full source here:
https://github.com/davecom/SwiftCSP/blob/master/SwiftCSP/SwiftCSPTests/SendMoreMoneyTests.swift

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction. This is under Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2) but I have tried the code in Xcode 7b4 (Swift 2.0) and see the same error.

Comment: Are you using Swift 2?

Comment: No, this is under Swift 1.2.  I have tried the code under 2.0 and see the same error though.

Comment: There's a good chance the compiler error is not actually related to the underlying problem. But beyond that, the source code itself doesn't really make any sense. A class with generic parameters that subclasses a class with generic parameters? I would strongly encourage you to take a step back and evaluate what part of your problem would actually benefit from generics.

Comment: Swift 1.2 doesn't allow a non-generic subclass of a generic class (Swift 2 does), hence the reason for SendMoreMoneyConstraint having generic constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't clear neither form the answer nor from the error but after copying your code it's clear:

You call the method like so:

```
let smmc = SendMoreMoneyConstraint<String, Int>(variables: variables)
csp.addConstraint(smmc)
```

but `csp` is declared as `CSP<String, Int>?` so you just have to add a `?` to make it work:

```
csp?.addConstraint(smmc)
```

Unfortunately the compiler doesn't give a useful error message.

Comment: Thanks, awesome catch! Such a dumb mistake and awful error message :)